# How can i make my pc shutdown after a certain amount of time without user activity?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, idle

I would like for my PC to shutdown after a certain amount of time of inactivity, like the way a screensaver is triggered, but i want it to completely shutdown instead of locking or showing a slideshow of pictures. I found some settings in kubuntu that allow this but only have a maximum range of 6 hours. I'd like to be able to customize that time to anything i want it to be. Is this possible? Would it be possible to edit the file in kubuntu where that value is stored to put in a value that i want? I am using Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1429919/edit) and add the version and flavor of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry for the confusion. I thought all the Ubuntu variants were the same. That the flavor was just the GUI interface. I didn't realize there are underlying differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

In `dconf-editor` under `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` set `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout` value (in seconds), and `sleep-inactive-ac-type` to `shutdown`.

Or via terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout <seconds>
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'shutdown'
```

replace `<seconds>` part with value in seconds.

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried running the terminal commands first, testing with 60 seconds value. I did not get an error, but the PC did not shutdown. I then installed dconf-editor and applied the settings there. The default values of 1200 and suspend were present when i checked the editor. I changed the values to 60 seconds and shutdown, but again this didn't work. Being that I am using Kubuntu, do i need to install something else to make these settings work?

Comment: oh, kubuntu... gsettings are for gnome. My bad I didn't registered you use KDE.